# Integrating Test Driven Development for web server legacy PHP / MSSQL / MySQL code

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2005, tdd, legacy

At work, I am working with this old legacy code modified Cake-PHP code that works with MSSQL and MySQL. It is used as a web server. We also have a automated task that runs to collect data.

Upgrading Cake-PHP will help, but we can't do that because one of the developers modified the internals of Cake-PHP. T-T

Recently I found SimpleTest, which is great. Very low dependency, easy to install, etc. 
However:

1. What is the best way to integrate test for PHP / MSSQL / MySQL setup?
2. We have a mock database of production, but even that change over time, so how can we Unit Test it. Specifically, how do we test each of queries code? We insert a lot and one time, and sometime it's impossible to write a delete sql for that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A down-to-earth answer would be to mock your database again and do not change it if not absolutely needed. When you do so, you should run your test and verify they don't fail.

Also as time goes by, try to isolate the layer that gets the raw data and your utility functions, so you can test the latter with known-and-manually-provided data.

Comment: that's possible, but the problem is we're also creating new tables from time to time and maintaining it will be extra work

Comment: import them manually, that's easy. more difficult is to import columns.  as long as your tests don't include stress testing, you may want to keep your testing database small (few rows per table) and mantain thos manually. The second paragraph of my answer still applies.